# Using retail price instead of sale price in interspire

Tags: php, interspire-shopping-cart

I want to use retail price instead of sale price on product if that product is on sale for a specific customer group.

I know that `interspire` use sale price if a product is on sale so I want that if someone logged in with that customer group then instead of sale price it use retail price however the product is on sale.

Does anyone know how it is possible in `interspire`?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please note that this isn't a homework service, you need to show what you have tried, and should provide a concrete example. Please read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].